# я хочу чтобы scanner,взял мой String и проверил его,если он есть в массиве obj,то пусть сработает метод который даст в print его номер и выйдет из if

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
           obj.add("Ajeet");
           obj.add("Harry");
           obj.add("Chaitanya");
           obj.add("Steve");
           obj.add("Anuj");

        Scanner sсanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ввод имени  : ");
        String s = sсanner.nextLine();

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Ajeet")){  
            int nas = obj.indexOf("Ajeet") ;
            System.out.println(nas);


            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Harry")){  
            int nas1 = obj.indexOf("Harry") ;
            System.out.println(nas1);

            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Chaitanya")){  
            int nas2 = obj.indexOf("Chaitanya") ;
            System.out.println(nas2);

            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Steve")){  
            int nas3 = obj.indexOf("Steve") ;
            System.out.println(nas3);

            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Anuj")){  
            int nas4 = obj.indexOf("Anuj") ;
            System.out.println(nas4);

        } 
          else {
                System.out.println("Такой имени нет  : ");
            }        
    }  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так чтоли?

```
ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
obj.add("Ajeet");
obj.add("Harry");
obj.add("Chaitanya");
obj.add("Steve");
obj.add("Anuj");

Scanner sсanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Ввод имени  : ");
String s = sсanner.nextLine();

int index = obj.indexOf(s);
if (index != -1) {
    System.out.println("Индекс имени " + s + ": " + index);
}else {
    System.out.println("Имени " + s + " в списке нет.");
}
```

---

Или с `ignorecase` возможно нужно

```
public static int checkInListAndGetIndex(List<String> list, String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(str))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
    obj.add("Ajeet");
    obj.add("Harry");
    obj.add("Chaitanya");
    obj.add("Steve");
    obj.add("Anuj");

    Scanner sсanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ввод имени  : ");
    String s = sсanner.nextLine();
    int index = checkInListAndGetIndex(obj, s);

    if (index != -1) {
        System.out.println("Индекс имени " + s + ": " + index);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Имени " + s + " в списке нет.");
    }

}
```

---

**P.S.** не забудьте на всякий случай делать `trim`, чтобы обрезать лишние пробелы у строки

Comment: Алексей Шиманский спасибо огромное

Comment: @GoyushMeherremov Или с ignorecase нужно - дописал вариант с обычным циклом. вроде должно работать

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, работает спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> obj = new HashSet<>();
    obj.add("ajeet");
    obj.add("harry");
    obj.add("chaitanya");
    obj.add("steve");
    obj.add("anuj");

    Scanner sсanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ввод имени  : ");
    String s = sсanner.nextLine();

     if (obj.contains(s.toLowerCase())){ 
        System.out.println("Name exist");

    }else { 
        System.out.println("Name not exist");
    }
```

Comment: Если вы хотите проверить наличие имени, то вам нужен не лист, а сет. Лист - обычный массив. Можете и сами догадаться, как осуществляется поиск в обычном неупорядоченном массиве. Сет осуществляет поиск по хешкоду. Разумеется, если у вас коллекция из 5 элементов разницы вы не почувствуете, но если элементов будет несколько миллионов, то разница будет ощутима. Хотя у листа тоже есть метод contains, определяющие, есть ли такой элемент